# When is a GWT label's layout calculated?

Tags: gwt, layout

I want to create a few labels, add them to an AbsolutePanel, and then calculate what positions they should go in. In order to do that calculation, I need to know how wide the browser has made the labels. When I call `label.getOffsetWidth()`, I get zero.

Is there anything I can do to force a layout calculation, or do I have to use something like `scheduleDeferred()` to set my positions after the layout has happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All widgets have a height and width of zero until the browser finishes rendering them. So you do have to use `scheduleDeferred` to wait until it happens.